# Changing Delphi XE5 workspace to Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Is it possible to change XE5's workspace to Delphi 7 like? Designing Forms inside a window is really pain and i would like to move components palette to up and design form outside of a canvas.

Comment: While I understand wanting to keep a workflow and system you're used to, try getting used to the new way. At some point the floating designer is going to go away. Plus, it's actually quite nice to work on - I don't miss the old system at all, it feels really clunky to me. Give it a chance :)

Comment: @DavidM:  Strange how one never sees qs on SO about how to get D7 to mimic XE+ in this respect.  I've tried v. hard to like the IDE "improvements" but it just seems to get worse at every turn.  Imo, EMB should stop frittering away their resources on stuff like this and leave the IDE to parties/products that are better at it (like MMX etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch to the *Classic Undocked* desktop in the desktop drop down. It's not identical to Delphi 7, but it is possibly as close as you'll get out of the box.

The other thing you can try is to enable the floating designer, disabled by default. More details here: http://francois-piette.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/enabling-floating-form-designer-in.html

You'll need to adapt the registry key to your version. The article has the key for XE4. For XE5 it is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0\Form Design
```

Set the `Embedded Designer` value to `False`. Restart your IDE and you've now got a familiar floating design surface.

Comment: But the form is still inside a window here. My only problem is the form inside a window.

Comment: You need to do part 2

Comment: @blacksun Have you got this sorted now?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Now i did it and it works as i expected. Thank you :)